# What are the different picture qualities in the Olympus OM-D E-M10II?

Tags: olympus, olympus-omd

For picture quality in the Olympus OM-D E-M10II there are many options. I know what RAW is, but what about the rest:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter on the left stands for Large, Medium, or Small, with respect to JPEG output dimensions, and the letters on the right stand for Fine or Normal JPEG compression quality. The "+RAW" options save a JPEG at that quality along with the RAW file.